# Python: Ridge regression - ''Ridge' object has no attribute 'coef_' after using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am using Python 3.6.5 and scikit-learn 0.23.2

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score

ridge = Ridge()

r_parameters = {'alpha':[1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 5, 10, 20]} # this is the Ridge regressor penalty, across different values

ridge_regressor = GridSearchCV(ridge, r_parameters, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 5)

ridge_regressor.fit(X,y)

ridge_best_params_ = ridge_regressor.best_params_
ridge_best_score_ = -ridge_regressor.best_score_
```

This has successfully provided me the best_params_ and best_score_ values. Meaning `.fit` has ran.
refit has not been adjusted, and hence it should be default `refit = True`

However when it comes to trying to return the coefficients of my ridge regression model:

```
for coef, col in enumerate(X.columns):
    print(f"{col}:  {ridge.coef_[coef]}")
```

It leads me to the error below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e59d1af522dc> in <module>
      2 
      3 for coef, col in enumerate(X.columns):
----> 4     print(f"{col}:  {ridge.coef_[coef]}")

AttributeError: 'Ridge' object has no attribute 'coef_
```

Appreciate any help for this.

Comment: `ridge_regressor` is fitted, thus it should have a `coef_` attribute

Comment: @FBruzzesi do you mean that if i use 
```for coef, col in enumerate(X.columns):
        print(f"{col}:  {ridge_regressor.coef_[coef]}")```
then I should get the coefficients?

Comment: Try `for coef, col in enumerate(X.columns): print(f"{col}:  {ridge_regressor.best_estimator_.coef_[coef]}")`

Comment: @FBruzzesi after changing from using `ridge.coef_` to `ridge_regressor.coef_`, i have obtained a new error code instead `TypeError: 'Ridge' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

`ridge` (the `Ridge` instance) doesn't actually get fitted when fitting `ridge_regressor` (the `GridSearchCV` instance); instead, clones of `ridge` are fitted, and one such is saved as `ridge.best_estimator_`.  So `ridge.best_estimator_.coef_` will contain the refitted model's coefficients.

Note that `GridSearchCV` does provide some convenience functions for accessing the `best_estimator_`; e.g. `ridge.score` is just shorthand for `ridge.best_estimator_.score`, and similarly for, `predict` and its variants.  But it doesn't provide this kind of passthrough for *all* of the methods/attributes of `best_estimator_`, and `coef_` is one of those not available.